# Joining a variable value and text value in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, variables, post, join, text

I want to join the value  of  `field = 'city'`  AND `'_id'` string. That is to say, `city_id`

But I want `city_id` as a variable for `$.post` variable as below :

```
$.post("jquery_post",{city_id : 8},function(data){........}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use array notation to assign or access dynamic property names in an object.

```
var params = {};
params[field+"_id"] = 8;
$.post("jquery_post", params, function(data){...});
```